# Swift: Split Strings from an `UILabel`

Tags: ios, string, uilabel

My app is a queue number announcer. it gets numbers on an `UILabel` and I'm looking for a way so I can export numbers from the `UILabel` and the give them conditions so that it plays each number's sounds. here's what I have so far:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

var Sound1:AVAudioPlayer?
var Sound2:AVAudioPlayer?
var Sound3:AVAudioPlayer?
var Sound4:AVAudioPlayer?
var Sound5:AVAudioPlayer?
var Sound6:AVAudioPlayer?
var Sound7:AVAudioPlayer?
var Sound8:AVAudioPlayer?
var Sound9:AVAudioPlayer?
var Sound10:AVAudioPlayer?

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

let numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
   return 3
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
   return numbers[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
   return numbers.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    let val1 = numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    let val2 = numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
    let val3 = numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]

    label.text = "\(val1) \(val2) \(val3)"


 }

fileprivate func num(_ i: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: i)
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed() {
    let currentNum = num(0) * 100 + num(1) * 10 + num(2)
    let nextNum = currentNum + 1

    pickerView.selectRow(nextNum % 1000 / 100, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    pickerView.selectRow(nextNum % 100 / 10, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
    pickerView.selectRow(nextNum % 10, inComponent: 2, animated: true)

    changeLabelText()
}

fileprivate func changeLabelText() {
    label.text = "\(num(0)) \(num(1)) \(num(2))"
}






//Announcer Button Icon Setting

@IBOutlet weak var speaker: UIButton!

@IBAction func speakerButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    speaker.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "speakerOn"), for: .highlighted)
}

//Announcer Button

@IBAction func soundPlayed(_ sender: Any) {
    accouncingNumbers()
}


    //Sounds imported here

    do

  {
    let audioURL1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "1", withExtension: "mp3")!
    Sound1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL1)
    Sound1?.prepareToPlay()

    let audioURL2 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "2", withExtension: "mp3")!
    Sound2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL2)
    Sound2?.prepareToPlay()

    let audioURL3 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "3", withExtension: "mp3")!
    Sound3 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL3)
    Sound3?.prepareToPlay()

    let audioURL4 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "4", withExtension: "mp3")!
    Sound4 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL4)
    Sound4?.prepareToPlay()

    let audioURL5 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "5", withExtension: "mp3")!
    Sound5 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL5)
    Sound5?.prepareToPlay()

    let audioURL6 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "6", withExtension: "mp3")!
    Sound6 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL6)
    Sound6?.prepareToPlay()

    let audioURL7 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "7", withExtension: "mp3")!
    Sound7 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL7)
    Sound7?.prepareToPlay()

    let audioURL8 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "8", withExtension: "mp3")!
    Sound8 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL8)
    Sound8?.prepareToPlay()

    let audioURL9 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "9", withExtension: "mp3")!
    Sound9 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL9)
    Sound9?.prepareToPlay()

    let audioURL10 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "10", withExtension: "mp3")!
    Sound10 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL10)
    Sound10?.prepareToPlay()

}


  catch

  {
     print(error)
    }

}
```

The numbers start from 1 to 999, and the printed numbers on the `UILabel` are from a 3-digit `UIPickerView`. how can I import the numbers from the `UILabel` to put them in a condition so it plays the right number announcer when user hits the `UIButton`?

Answer (score 1):

*Don't* "import the numbers from the UILabel". The label is *view*. The numbers are *model* (data). You should *never* be using a view as your sole repository of an important piece of data. If you're going to need these numbers later, save them as data beforehand, so that you can readily retrieve them later.